# How to find DLL EntryPoint?

Tags: c#, dll

simple question:
 How I can find out commands for a DLLImport in C#.Net and / or the Entry Points of the DLL?

Background:
I will use the MobileDevice-Libary from ITunes to send commands to an Iphone. I know round about 90% of the DLL-Commands from another open source project, but there are still 10% left, and I need a command of this 10%.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) can list all exports for a DLL.

Answer (score 3):

These days you want to use Dependencies

https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pinvoke interop assistant which is included in [CLRInsideOut2008_01.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/CLRInsideOut2008_01.exe)

I have used it a lot to help with pinvoke definitions it has saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the dll in a good text editor (like UltraEdit or so). You'll read all the functions on board on the right hand side ASCII pane. If you already know a few functions, do ctrl+f to find that one, the rest of the functions implemented will be presented in the neighborhood.
Grtz
E

Comment: Or, drag DLL onto Visual Studio, and it opens up the manifest.

Comment: @DougNull FYI, it looks like the manifest doesn't always list the functions. I'm guessing you were looking at well-formed dlls, and I am not so fortunate. Ed.'s text editor suggestion does appear to work on this deficient-manifest dll, with the functions displaying in a list after the dll's name, near the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

[PE File Reader](http://www.objectmedia.ltd.uk/freeSoftware/peFileDLL.html) is a DLL (with source in C++) that can read PE files and give you the entry point for the DLL.

The source is provided unencumbered by the GPL, so you can use the source and/or the DLL in your project as you wish.