# How can I know the function which represented by the Ordinals sign specified in the EntryPoint

Tags: c#, winapi, dllimport

All, As the title shows , If I have the code looks like below.

```
[DllImport("twain_32.dll", EntryPoint="#1")]
private static extern TwRC DSixfer( [In, Out] TwIdentity origin, [In] TwIdentity dest, TwDG dg, TwDAT dat, TwMSG msg, ref IntPtr hbitmap );
```

How can I know what exactly the function does that `#number` represent for? Is there any tool to view the list of function like below?

```
#1 Afunction(...)
#2 Bfunction(...)
#3 Afunction(...)
...
#n Bfunction(...)
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2491433/1850797)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two tools spring to mind:

1. [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).
2. [`dumpbin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx) from the MS tool set.

Comment: +1 - Dependency Walker is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I like [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/download-pe-explorer.htm) very much.
Here's a look at `twain_32.dll` from its perspective:

[image]

The fact that it isn't free doesn't mean it's not worth the money.
It also includes a 30 day trial and eventually you could look for free alternatives on the Internet.