# How can I resolve "entry point not found exception" error while importing DLL to c#?

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport, entry-point

In my code I want to import some methods but still facing error

1. Tested both 32 and 64 bit DLL
2. The DLL is beside the executive file
3. There isn't any dependency for DLL and is unmanaged and standalone

But it still have enry point error
*** before all thanks helping me***
[error while debugging and importing dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUNH9.jpg)

```
    [DllImport("sg_api.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern sgStatus sgOpenDevice(ref int device);
```

Comment: WHere did you get the dll from? If it is your own C or C++ dll then please add relevant functions header

Comment: Well, the error message tells you that there is no method called "sgOpenDevice" in the DLL. Are you sure it is exported with this name and not e.g. with a mangled C++ name?

Comment: Trust the system. If it tells you there is no function with that name, trust that information

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491433/how-to-find-dll-entrypoint. There is mention of a tool that can list all entry points in a DLL. Maybe that way you can find the entrypoint you are looking for.